# From long (with multiple categories) to wide format

Tags: r

I have a data frame in a kind of long format, where each column can assume multiple values (separated by commas):

`dataset_long = data.frame(id=1:5, type=c("A", "A, B", "C, A", "C", "A"))`

`> dataset_long
  id type
1  1    A
2  2 A, B
3  3 C, A
4  4    C
5  5    A`

I want to transform it to a wide format, to be used in a regression:

`dataset_wide = data.frame(id=1:5, 
                          type_A = c(1,1,1,0,1), 
                          type_B = c(0,1,0,0,0), 
                          type_C = c(0,0,1,1,0))`

`> dataset_wide
  id type_A type_B type_C
1  1      1      0      0
2  2      1      1      0
3  3      1      0      1
4  4      0      0      1
5  5      1      0      0`

It is somehow similar to a "one hot encoding", but each line may belong to several categories.

Is there any elegant way to go from `dataset_long` to `dataset_wide`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by splitting the 'type' at the delimiter with `separate_rows`, create an column of 1s. and 'spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset_long %>% 
    separate_rows(type) %>% 
    mutate(type = paste0('type_', type)) %>% 
    mutate(ind = 1) %>% 
    spread(type, ind, fill = 0)
#  id type_A type_B type_C
#1  1      1      0      0
#2  2      1      1      0
#3  3      1      0      1
#4  4      0      0      1
#5  5      1      0      0
```

---

Or using `strsplit` and `table` from `base R`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(dataset_long$type),
        ', '),  dataset_long$id))[2:1])
```

---

Or in a single line with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(setNames(strsplit(as.character(dataset_long$type), ', '), dataset_long$id))
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code will produce the result you showed in your example

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataset_long = data.frame(id=1:5, type=c("A", "A, B", "C, A", "C", "A"))

dataset_wide <- dataset_long %>% mutate(type_A=ifelse(regexpr('A', type)>0, 1, 0), 
                                        type_B=ifelse(regexpr('B', type)>0, 1, 0), 
                                        type_C=ifelse(regexpr('C', type)>0, 1, 0))
dataset_wide
#>   id type type_A type_B type_C
#> 1  1    A      1      0      0
#> 2  2 A, B      1      1      0
#> 3  3 C, A      1      0      1
#> 4  4    C      0      0      1
#> 5  5    A      1      0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

However, that is not a "long to wide" rearrangement of the dataset. Both your original dataset_long and the new dataset_wide have a single row per ID. Generally when we say "long" we are talking about multiple rows per ID being collapsed to a "wide" format with one row per ID.

Most people would call this simply creating three indicator (or dummy) variables signifying the presence of A, B or C in the original text string.

P.S. My use of ifelse() and regexpr()>0 are almost certainly not the most succinct way of creating these three indicator variables. Those are just functions I usually default to in my own code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up adapting your suggestion, but we have to agree @akrun 's anwer is simpler. PS: Thank you also for clarifying the use of long/wide formats! :)